# most Pythonic way of achieveing these 4 lines?

Tags: python, text

I have a csv cell value, `row[13]` that contains the following text: `POINT (174.29635 -41.60557)`

I need to strip out the text and brackets, and convert the two numbers to float, each assigned to a var:-

```
geo_pair = row[13].replace("POINT (", "")
geo_pair = geo_pair.replace(")", "")
self.longitude, self.latitude = geo_pair.split(" ")
self.longitude, self.latitude = float(self.longitude), float(self.latitude)
```

I'm pretty sure there is a cleaner way of doing this, and I wondered what someone who knows what they are doing would do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the format is fixed and consists of prefix, data, and suffix, I would use slicing to remove prefix and suffix: `map(float, s[7:-1].split())`.

This is clear and simple at the same time:

```
>>> s = "POINT (174.29635 -41.60557)"
>>> longitude, latitude = map(float, s[7:-1].split())
```

This also works upon sign changes or when the number of decimal places changes.

And by the way, as long as you are not parsing tons of input, it does not really matter which way to chose. It's mostly a matter of taste and most likely not performance-critical in your case. So don't spend too much time with this :-).

Comment: I think about this one because it seems the format of the text is fixed.

Comment: Appreciate the edit, thanks. This is actually an incredibly useful learning exercise, I know I've learnt some really useful stuff just by seeing how others address this simple problem. Thanks, its really appreciated. (I also see how the bracket markers are important, and allow units and direction changes :))

Answer (score 3):

Use the regex?

```
>>> map(float, re.search(r'\((.*)\)', s).group(1).split())
[174.29635, -41.60557]
>>>
```

Comment: I did think about regex, but considered not to use another lib module. Thank you for your suggestion :)

Comment: If the format of the text is not fixed, regex is worth trying. But if the format is fixed, Jan-Philip's solution is good.

Comment: As these are geo, any movement of the source over a unit threshold (99.9999 to 100.0000) would result in an error. Also changes from - to + (as there is no + marker). That makes the regex idea more robust I think.

Comment: @JayGattuso: see edit to my answer. Change in sign or number of decimal places is not a problem.

Comment: Yes. It is not the format in the braces matter. It is the `POINT ()` that matters.@Jan-PhilipGehrcke

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
>>> a, b = map(float, row.translate(None, "POINT()").split())
>>> a
174.29635
>>> b
-41.60557
```

where

```
row = "POINT (174.29635 -41.60557)"
```

Comment: Very nice. I've leant about `map` and part of `translate` from this! What does the `None` do?

Comment: The first argument to `translate` is a translation table, when `None` is provided, it deletes everything in the second argument.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is way too cryptic for a simple task like this (interesting approach, nevertheless).

Comment: That's because it returns a `map` object, just doing `list()` on it does the trick. Not worth the downvote IMO.

Comment: No, because the `.translate()` call for unicode requires a dictionary instead. Using `.translate()` to remove non-digits feels.. icky.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke : Appreciate the downvote. OP found it useful and learnt something from it, my work here was done.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : Can you point me towards a similar alternative for Python 3? I would like to know more about it. :)

Comment: `.translate(dict.fromkeys(ord(c) for c in 'POINT()'))`. This creates a dictionary with `None` values and integer keys; codepoints mapping to `None` causes those codepoints to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I use `split(sep1, 1)[-1].split(sep2, 1)[0]`:

```
geo_pair = row[13].split("POINT (", 1)[-1].split(")", 1)[0]
self.longitude, self.latitude = map(float, geo_pair.split())
```

Comment: A two stage approach. I can sort of follow this. What does the number `1` in the `split` do?

Comment: @JayGattuso, Split only once(1). For example: `'a b c'.split(' ')` yields `['a', 'b', 'c']`,  but `'a b c'.split(' ', 1)` yields `['a', 'b c']`.